# How to upload/send files as email attachment from upload via JQuery Ajax POST call to MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, http-post, form-data

I noticed modern browsers excluding IE would show a fake path in Jquery object, which is a security protection to avoid server accessing client side physical drive via browser.

I saw some other posts here and there using formData. I do think it will work with file or maybe files only. But I am in a situation which needs to pass some other information like ID and a couple of string values with the file(s) uploaded to the backend.

My original implementation is like:

Ajax call:

```
var emails = {
                RequestId: requestId, 
                ToEmails: toEmails,  
                CcEmails: ccEmails,  
                FileList: fileList   
            };

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SendEmails")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(emails),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
    }
});
```

.Net Core MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SendEmails([FromBody]ToCcEmails emails)
{
}
```

Complex object type class:

```
public class ToCcEmails
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ToEmails { get; set; }
    public string CcEmails { get; set; }
    public List<string> FileList { get; set; }
}
```

What should I change to my ajax code or even the MVC action file to make it works with the formData solution or any other solution properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do think it will work with file or maybe files only. But I am in a
> situation which needs to pass some other information like ID and a
> couple of string values with the file(s) uploaded to the backend.

If you want to post data with files,your model seems do not correct,here is a working demo below:

Model:

```
public class ToCcEmails
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ToEmails { get; set; }
    public string CcEmails { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> FileList { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="RequestId" />
    <input type="text" name="ToEmails" />
    <input type="text" name="CcEmails" />
    <input type="file" multiple name="FileList" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $("input[name='FileList']").change(function () {
        var data = new FormData();

        $("input[name='FileList']").each(function () {
            var ReadyToUpload = $(this)[0].files;
            if (ReadyToUpload.length > 0) {
                $.each(ReadyToUpload, function (i, file) {
                    data.append("FileList", file);
                });
            }
        });

        $("form input[type='text']").each(function (x, y) {
            data.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SendEmails")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
           // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
            }
        });
    })
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SendEmails([FromForm]ToCcEmails emails)
{
    return true;
}
```

Result:
[image]